# I want to do this to 2 different lists consisting of strings

Tags: python, string, list, function

I want to do this to 2 different lists consisting of strings with:

```
list_A = ['Krish', 'Ram', 'Rajaa']
list_B = ['Sweet', 'Joy', 'Discipline']
```

I've written:

```
def Srinivasaragavansir(x,y):
     out= x[0].upper() + x[1:] + " " + y[0].upper() + y[1:]
     return(out)
```

When I run `Srinivasaragavansir(list_A,list_B)` I get:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

Comment: What do you want the output to be? Because x[1:] and y[1:] are list, not str which cannot be concatenate

Comment: Please post comprehensive question title, this title make no sense

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

So, you are adding string to the list.

Ex.

`x[0].upper()` returns a string and `x[1:]` returns a list, so here you are adding  a list to a string which is wrong.

If you want to add, then you can add lists together:

```
x[1:] + y[1:]
['Ram','Rajaa''Joy','Discipline]
```

and to add strings together

```
x[0].upper() +" "+y[0].upper()
"KRISH SWEET"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work you i guess

```
import functools
def Srinivasaragavansir(x, y):
    out1 = functools.reduce(lambda i,j: str(i) + ' ' + str(j),x[1:],x[0].upper())
    out2 = functools.reduce(lambda i, j: str(i) + ' ' + str(j), y[1:], y[0].upper())
    out = out1 + ' ' + out2
    return out
list_A = ['Krish', 'Ram', 'Rajaa']
list_B = ['Sweet', 'Joy', 'Discipline']
print(Srinivasaragavansir(list_A,list_B))
```